# ARCore eyes tracking

Tags: java, opengl-es, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm new to ARCore, and I'm trying to track both eyes by using Google's own example of augmented faces. The problem is Google has created region poses for NOSE_TIP, FOREHEAD_LEFT, FOREHEAD_RIGHT only. I'm using the latest version of ARCore at the time of writing this, which is 1.20.
In the onDrawFrame method I'm doing this:

```
    face.getRegionPose(RegionType.NOSE_TIP).toMatrix(noseMatrix, 0);
    face.getRegionPose(RegionType.NOSE_TIP).toMatrix(noseMatrix2, 0);
    noseObject.updateModelMatrix(noseMatrix, scaleFactor);
    noseObject.draw(viewMatrix, projectionMatrix, colorCorrectionRgba, DEFAULT_COLOR);
    noseObject2.updateModelMatrix(noseMatrix2, scaleFactor);
    noseObject2.draw(viewMatrix, projectionMatrix, colorCorrectionRgba, DEFAULT_COLOR);
```

So, I'm wondering what to do get the eyes position.
Thanks to everyone who's going to help me in any possible way.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this blog](https://creativetech.blog/home/face-landmarks-for-arcore-augmented-faces) post to see how it is done with ARCore and Sceneform. Hope it will give you some ideas